# How to implement Context API in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just start looking for changing theme globally, and found [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) can do that,

but I've a problem to implement the example code to my react native project,

I've tried this code:

```
//themeContext.js

const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: '#000000',
    background: '#eeeeee',
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: '#ffffff',
    background: '#222222',
  },
};

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: themes.dark,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
})

//App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {InitialScreen} from './routes/routes';
import { ThemeContext } from './Component/themeContext';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      theme:themes.light,
      toggleTheme:this.toggleTheme
    }
    this.toggleTheme=()=>{
      this.setState(state=>({
        theme:state.theme === themes.dark ? themes.light : themes.dark
      }))
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.disableYellowBox = true;
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        //this is Login.js
        <InitialScreen/>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

//Login.js

import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { ThemeContext } from '../Component/themeContext';

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {({theme, toggleTheme})=>{
          <View style={{backgroundColor:theme.background}}>
            <Text>{this.state}</Text>
          </View>
        }}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

but i have an error `Can't find variable: Component`, i don't know where should i put `import React from 'react';` cause i think I've add `Component` var in `app.js` and `login.js`

any help would be appreciate

Comment: Hey @flix are themes work with u?

Answer (score 0):

Replace next string in the top of your Login.js instead of

```js
import React from 'react';
```

with

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Another way is to replace

```js
export default class Login extends Component {
}
```

with

```js
export default class Login extends React.Component {
}
```

Comment: after add `import React, { Component } from 'react';` I got new error `Can't find variable: React` what happened?

Comment: Exactly same code works fine in your `App.js` so something wrong or confused at your side. Try restart cra app (or webpack dev server), if not helps remove `node_modules` and refetch packages

Answer (score 0):

In App.js updated your `App` component class defintion by replacing `Component` with `React.Component` as shown:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

   /* existing component code */
}
```

Make the same change in Login.js as well:

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {

   /* existing component code */
}
```

These changes will cause the `Login` and `App` components to extend from the `Component` class as defined on the `React` object exported `from 'react'`.

Comment: @flix are you still importing react via this method? `import React from 'react';` ?

Comment: just in case i used `export default class MyClass extends React.Component {...}` I use `import React from 'react';` as you suggested

Comment: @flix what is `MyClass`? are you sure this code is causing the error, or are you getting an error from some other part of your project?

Comment: `MyClass` is another word of `Login` and `App`, the problem fix when i add `import React from 'react';` in `themeContext.js`. I thought I don't need to import it because the docs just say __Make sure the shape of the default value passed to
// createContext matches the shape that the consumers expect!__

Comment: @flix oh - yes, you'll need to import `react` in modules where you're using the react context API (assumed you were doing that). Hope this has helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in **themeContext.js** file

you use `createContext()` but you don't import React so you will get can't find React

it's should be like this

```
import React from 'react';
export const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: '#000000',
    background: '#eeeeee',
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: '#ffffff',
    background: '#222222',
  },
};
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: themes.dark,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
});
```

And in **Login.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
```